# Promise not completing when using Edge with Node

Tags: c#, node.js, typescript, async-await, edgejs

I am working out how best to consume my C# dlls using Edgejs for Node.

One proxy function in Node looks like this (a class method in Typescript):

```
readSettings(args: ReadSettingsParams) : Promise<response> {
    let $engine = this;
    var proxy = edge.func({
        assemblyFile: "C:\\Development\\IAStash\\GLReport\\GLReport\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\GLReportEngine.dll",
        typeName: "GLReportEngine.edgeGLReport",
        methodName: "readSettings"
    });
    return new Promise<response>(function (resolve, reject) {
        args.instance = $engine.instance;
        proxy(args, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When my complex task in c# is synchronous, everything works as expected, but when I move the core of the c# function into a task:

```
return await Task.Run<object>( () => { do some stuff });
```

When I use the above pattern, the resolve(result) line is hit, the result is correct in the watch window, but any .then or Q.all structures that are composed do not respond to resolve(result) having been executed.

I have found that if I console.log("x"); before the proxy callback returns, then my composed .then and Q.all structures fire as expected. i.e. this version works:

```
readSettings(args: ReadSettingsParams) : Promise<response> {
    let $engine = this;
    var proxy = edge.func({
        assemblyFile: "C:\\Development\\IAStash\\GLReport\\GLReport\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\GLReportEngine.dll",
        typeName: "GLReportEngine.edgeGLReport",
        methodName: "readSettings"
    });
    return new Promise<response>(function (resolve, reject) {
        args.instance = $engine.instance;
        proxy(args, function(error, result) {
            console.log("GLReportProxy.readSettings proxy returns, Err = " + (!!error));
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My c# routine in this case reads an xml file, deserializes it and returns it:

```
    public Task<object> readSettings(object args)
    {
        if (args != null && typeof(System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject).IsAssignableFrom(args.GetType()))
        {
            var argdict = (IDictionary<string, object>)args;
            if (argdict.ContainsKey("report"))
            {
                reportsettingsfile = argdict["report"].ToString();
            }

            return Task.Run<object>(
                () => {
                    if (File.Exists(reportsettingsfile))
                    {
                        var xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReportSettings.report));
                        string settingstext = File.ReadAllText(reportsettingsfile);
                        using (var tre = new StringReader(settingstext))
                        {
                            reportSettings = (ReportSettings.report)xser.Deserialize(tre);
                        }
                        return new { result = true, model = reportSettings };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new { result = false, error = "File not found" };
                    }
                });
        } else
        {
            return Task.FromResult<object>(new { result = false, error = "Expected (input) object but can't read it." });
        }
    }
```

This is fairly simple. I figure that I've got problems in my use of async/await, that causes problems in Node. To be fair though, I had expected promises to be robust. There could be issues with my use of Typescript, Node, Edge, Promises, Q.

If anybody knows what's happening, and why logging to the console fixes the problem. I'd appreciate any help!

Mark

Comment: It seems that this is a known issue in edge:
https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/325
I guess that the question is therefore, how can the streams be unlocked without logging?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is an issue when there is a http.listener and a c# edge proxy callback in the same process. There could be other combinations, but some interplay between libraries is the root cause.

Since this issue is unresolved according to edgejs, the console.log method is a good workaround, particularly if you don't mind writing some helpful message to the log window.

**console.log** is a good workaround, but I wanted something silent. I notice that console internally has _stdout. If you execute **console._stdout.write('');** you get a silent unlock. in Typescript you have to do **(console as any)._stdout.write('');**.

I do this on entry to the edge proxy callback. e.g.

```
readSettings(args: ReadSettingsParams) : Promise<response> {
    let $engine = this;
    var proxy = edge.func({
        assemblyFile: "C:\\Development\\IAStash\\GLReport\\GLReport\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\GLReportEngine.dll",
        typeName: "GLReportEngine.edgeGLReport",
        methodName: "readSettings"
    });
    return new Promise<response>(function (resolve, reject) {
        args.instance = $engine.instance;
        proxy(args, function(error, result) {
            (console as any)._stdout.write('');
            //console.log("GLReportProxy.readSettings proxy returns, Err = " + (!!error));
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Clearly you could log something as indicated in the comment.